# session is lost after successful login?

Tags: spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.0.2.  All the application pages are secured,
so you must be authenticated to see them.

I'm using https protocol.

I have a strange problem: after successful login and going to the requested page, when I tried to open any link to other pages in the application the session is invalidated or lost and the user becomes anonymous and redirected to the login page.  I got this from debugging:

```
No HttpSession currently exists
No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
```

After reviewing the code many times, nothing in the code is invalidating the session. Any ideas? Why might something like this might happen?

Answer (score 2):

Could be an cookie domain or cookie path problem. Is you're https login page on the same path/domain?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have been trying to login after migrating from Glassfish to WildFly. Each time I successfully logged in using spring security, the session was lost, and and an anonymous user created, causing the login page to reload. I cleared all localhost browser cookies, and could finally log in!

Comment: @ChrisRitchie Thank you for your comment. I had the same issue, and clearing the browser cookies fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I migrate from Jboss 7.0 to Wildfly 8.0, in Jboss 7.0 the behavior was OK (login success and redirect to index page), but in Wilfly the login was success, redirect to index page but later the session was lost and Spring Security redirect to login page again.

I saw the cookies in web navigator (chrome) and there two cookies JSESSIONID in the same domain (127.0.0.1) with diferent values. I deleted all cookies and did the procedure of logging again, and this was ok.

Answer (score 1):

app-security,xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">  

    </global-method-security>
    <http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">  
         <remember-me token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"
         token-validity-seconds="1209600"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/error.jsp"/> 

        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/images/**" filters="none" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/files/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/login" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/register" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/forgotPassword" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/changePassword" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/p/**" access="isAuthenticated()"  />
        <custom-filter position="LAST" ref="rememberMeFilter"/>    
        <form-login                 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"         
            login-page="/p/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/p/login?login_error=1"     
            authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationHandler"            
        />

        <logout />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationHandler" class="com.myAuthenticationHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="com.rememberMeFilter" />

    <beans:bean id="tokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean> 


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
    <authentication-provider>

            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>           
             <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
             users-by-username-query="SELECT u.username,u.password,u.enabled   
                                FROM Users u where u.username=lower(?)"    
        authorities-by-username-query="SELECT a.username,a.authority    
                                FROM Users u, authorities a   
                                WHERE u.username=a.username
                                and u.username=lower(?) and enabled=1"/>

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    </beans:beans>
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Please provide some context surrounding your answer, and see the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on how to write great answers.